# Sending authenticated e-mails through ASP.NET MVC application using smtp server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, smtp, exchange-server

I have an ASP.NET MVC application, from which I want to send emails. I am using the SMTP Virtual Server to do it. I want the sender to be verified, so that the only a person having an exchange account can send an email and from his account only.
Is there any built in support for it in SMTP Server given by IIS or Exchange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to configure your Exchange Server to only allow authenticated access to the SMTP. [This article](http://help.globalscape.com/help/me3/configuring_authenticated_access_to_exchange.htm) and [this TechNet post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/dabdd759-d395-48fc-b3c4-c610eba46702/exchange-server-smtp-authentication) describe how.